# Changing Font Size on DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, fonts

I've been attempting to change the font size of the text within a Data Grid upon choosing a text size from a value fetched from a database. So far I've only managed to change the text within the grid to either be bold or regular and be static size:

```
GridName.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial",15.00F,FontStyle.Bold);
```

The code above works, however, I want the "15.00F" to be variable, the value I want to pull it from is stored within a text string, I've tried to convert the font size(string) to a double but it's not letting me use it as the font size. How do I convert a string to a variable that I can replace the fixed font size above (if that makes sense).

```
GridName.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial",varFontSize,FontStyle.Bold);
```

Above is essentially what I'm after, I just don't know how to get a valid emSize in the varFontSize variable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try converting it to a `float`, not a double. And make sure the string  doesn't have `F` on the end - that's only for literals in the code.

Comment: How is the varFontSize being created? That's probably the issue. Also, use a float, not a double.

Comment: @Blorgbeard nailed it. So simple yet overlooked by myself. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Font constructor require a Float value

```
public Font(
    FontFamily family,
    float emSize,
    FontStyle style
)
```

In order to parse a string into a float you need to use

```
float varFontSize= Single.Parse(value);
```

Then you can

```
GridName.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial",varFontSize,FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think Blorgbeard answer your question, the value needs to be in float type.

Comment: Not an Answer, just +1 his Comment